# iOS: Is it possible to create custom xib control templates?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

Does anybody know if it is possible to create custom controls for using in Interface Builder like UIButton with a lot of settings on Utility panel?

If to say more specifically: I want to create my custom UILabel class and xib object template for it where I could add my custom settings on Utility panel. For example I want to have possibility to set name of my custom font by using Interface builder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't. You can create your own controls using xib, but then you should add it programmatically, you can't use it directly from Interface Builder.